# PROBLEMAS CON FOREACH Y DATAGRIDVIEW C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
string cant = "";
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Inventario from Inventario where Descripcion = @desc", cone);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvagregarp.Rows)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Descripcion"].Value));
                cone.Open();
                cant = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                int st = 0;
                int.TryParse(cant, out st);
                string d = row.Cells["Inventario"].Value.ToString();
                int r = 0;
                int.TryParse(d, out r);
                MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());
                int tot = r + st;
                MessageBox.Show(tot.ToString());
                cone.Close();
                MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("update Inventario set Inventario = '" + tot.ToString() + "' where Descripcion = @desc", cone);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Descripcion"]));
                cone.Open();
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cone.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Productos agregados");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cone.Close();
        }
```

**El problema es que me está tirando el error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'"
Ya di el seguimiento por pasos y el código debería funcionar. ¿Alguien sabe porque me tira éste error?**

Como nota el error me lo da aquí **"string d = row.Cells["Inventario"].Value.ToString();"**

Comment: si lo seguiste, sabes en que linea lo tira y cual es el objeto que es nulo... entonces?

Comment: El problema es ese. Hace todo el código y al terminar de ejecutarlo es cuando da el error. Supongo que será porque se acaban los rows del dgv pero no tendría sentido, ¿No?

Comment: saca los try catch y fijate efectivamente en que linea y que objeto lo tira.. estas seguro que es aca???

Comment: Sí, esta en el código dentro de un botón y es todo el código que hay dentro del mismo. Actualicé la pregunta agregando exactamente en que línea me aparece eso.

Comment: y que da nulo? row? cells? value?

Comment: me dice que el get para el Value: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get devolvió null.

Comment: Entonces, esa celda no tiene ningun valor... puede ser que tengas una fila vacia en tu grilla?

Comment: No, es que la grilla tiene una sola línea y en esa celda sí tiene valor, un número. ¿Puede ser que el problema esté en que solo tiene una sola línea?

Comment: Bien al parecer, después de algunas pruebas. El error es que ejecuta el código aún despues que la grilla no tenga más datos para leer y por eso devuelve un "Null". ¿Como podría cambiar que siga ejecutando el foreach en casillas vacías?

Comment: Solucionado. Usando un if para validar si el siguiente cell no devuelve null y así se cancela la función para evitar el error!

Comment: Tu grilla debe tener la propiedad de agregar una nueva fila automaticamente (no recuerdo el nombre) encendida... y por eso tiene una fila mas de lo que vosnpensas... fijate si no ves una fila vacia cuando la mostras

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había fijado en eso. Ya mismo lo desactivo.